# Get TimeZone by lat and long in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, datetime, timezone, latitude-longitude

I need Time Zone by lat,long ,for that I have found this post helpful [Get Time Zone From Lat Long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates). As described in this link if I use [Google Api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/start) then its response is

```
 {
        "dstOffset" : 3600,
       "rawOffset" : -18000,
       "status" : "OK",
       "timeZoneId" : "America/New_York",
       "timeZoneName" : "Eastern Daylight Time"
    }
```

but my requirement is that if India`s Time Zone is 5:30 then I need it to be 5.5
or if Any country time zone is 7:0 then 7.0. My question is how I get timezone from lat long also in custom form as specified above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line may help you.....

```
double zone = (responseObject.get("rawOffset").getAsInt() + responseObject.get("dstOffset").getAsInt()) / 3600.0;
```

get rawOffset and dstOffset from the response and add them, and divide them on 3600..... rawOffset is the GMT +- timezone in seconds and dstOffset is daylight saving offset in second (if a country is having dst it will be 3600 else 0)

Comment: its not the exact answer but you should get the idea

Comment: can you please explain about line of code, I don't know much about time zone

Comment: there you go @KulwinderSinghRahal I updated my answer

Comment: and I'm assuming you are familiar with JSON parsin

Comment: can you also suggest me what is better way to get RawOffset and DstOffset from lat long without google api

Comment: I'm afraid not, I myself am using this and I think it is most reliable

Comment: if you are using standard version it's free see [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/#details)

Comment: can you please accept the answer if it worked for you @KulwinderSinghRahal

Comment: yes I will Accept the answere after trying it ,please give me some time