# How to get timezone based on current latitude and longitude?

Tags: android

I am getting current latitude and longitude in map box, I need current timezone based on current latitude and longitude.

For example.My device time is the USA but my location showing in India so I need India timezone.Can you please help me.

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        try {
            mLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            Log.i("EE","mLatLngmLatLng"+mLatLng);
            String time = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(location.getTime());

            Log.i("EE","time----"+time);
            Log.i("EE","vlocation.getTime()----"+location.getTime());

            updateCamera();
            if (mMarker != null) {
                updateMarker();
            }else{
                addMarker();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16086964/2906153

Comment: https://github.com/drtimcooper/LatLongToTimezone

Comment: hello Kalai , did u check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Get address by Geocoder and identify country, When you will get the country name It will be easy for you to identify the time Zone.

```
  private void getAddressFromLocation(double latitude, double longitude) {

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);


    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address fetchedAddress = addresses.get(0);
            StringBuilder strAddress = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < fetchedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                strAddress.append(fetchedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append(" ");
            }

            txtLocationAddress.setText(strAddress.toString());

        } else {
            txtLocationAddress.setText("Searching Current Address");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        printToast("Could not get address..!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Abhishek,USA country have many timezone ,how to find particular timezone for lat and long

Comment: can yo checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45767424/get-timezone-by-lat-and-long-in-android @kalaivani

Comment: I checked , but there is no solution.they given like this double zone = (responseObject.get("rawOffset").getAsInt() + responseObject.get("dstOffset").getAsInt()) / 3600.0;.I dont rawoffset value